# how set text from sqlite database in QComboBox?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

hi i make an search function and search record frint combobox but value not print

```
def searchEmpolyee(self):

    searchresult = self.b1.text()

    self.conn = sqlite3.connect("databas.db")
    self.c = self.conn.cursor()
    result = self.c.execute("SELECT * from Hr_depart WHERE id='"+searchresult+"'")
    row = result.fetchone()

    self.b1.setText(str(row[0]))
    self.b2.setItemText(row[1]) # b2 is object name QcomboBox
    self.b3.setText(str(row[2]))
    self.b4.setText(str(row[3]))
    self.b5.setText(str(row[4]))
    self.b6.setText(str(row[5]))
    self.b7.setText(str(row[6]))
    self.b8.setItemText(row[7])  # b8 is object name QcomboBox

    QMessageBox.information(QMessageBox(), 'Successful', " "+searchresult+"  :Record Successfully Found!")
    self.conn.commit()
    self.c.close()
    self.conn.close()
```

Comment: Is the searchresult is a department name?.. then change the id in where condition.

Comment: yes parameter search value through where cluase

Comment: which column you need to compare with from Hr_depart?. is it name?

Comment: `QComboBox.setItemText()` takes two parameters, int *index* and str *text*, but you've only supplied one.

Comment: databse id i search record through primary ID searchresult  id DB ID primary

Comment: @ alec  i want to search record through primary ID after search record result print in QlineEdit or comboBox, i have face problem value not print in Qcombo box

Comment: what input you will give in searchresult , that  am asking?  is it id then ok check comment from alec may it help you, or else if you are giving text in searchresult then you need to change query

Comment: SELECT * from Hr_depart WHERE id='"+1+"' , next query like 2 primary key ID

Comment: self.b2.setItemText(1,row[1])

Comment: @Vishnu VaNnErI    it show me console error when i set self.b2.setItemText(1,row[1])   **Exception "unhandled TypeError"
setItemText(self, int, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'**

Comment: @Mayo-Soft yes, exactly, the first argument *has* to be the index of the entry for which you want to set the text. Please, read more carefully the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcombobox.html#setItemText).